# ngif is not working properly

Tags: angularjs

I want to use ngif to check some int that comes back from a function, and if its bigger then 0 I want to present it, so this is what I did:

```
 <div>
<b>Name:</b>{{person.getName()}}<b>balance left:</b>
<div *ngif="person.getBalance()>0">{{bulk.getBalance()}}</div>
</div>
```

but i get a blanc page, but if i remove the ngif its fine, but I need it, what am I doing wrong?

this is a data that comes from an array called "person"

tnx

Comment: It's capital I in *ngIf not small i.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misspelled it. Try removing the * and put a - between ng and if.

```
<div ng-if="person.getBalance()>0">{{bulk.getBalance()}}</div>
```

I think that that doesn't work either because you're evaluating a method. Instead store Balance in a variable like this:

```
<div ng-if="person.balance>0">{{bulk.balance}}</div>
```

Execute the getBalance method in your controller.